# Symfony Doctrine get entity through another entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 entities: User, ImaginaryBankAccount and Recharge. One user has one ImaginaryBankAccount and ImaginaryBankAccount can have more than one Recharges. And I want to select from DB all Recharges that belongs to one user.

I have this query:

```
$resResults = $query->getResult();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT rec
                           FROM AppBundle:Recharge rec
                           WHERE rec.dateTime > :tresholdDate
                            AND rec.imaginaryBankAccount.user = :user
                           ORDER BY rec.dateTime'
)->setParameter('tresholdDate', $dateXDaysBack)
 ->setParameter('user', $filter->getUser());
$recResults = $query->getResult();
```

But it throws error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 223 near 'user = :user
>   ': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Recharge has no field or association named imaginaryBankAccount.user

How can I achieve my goal with Doctrine2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a JOIN clause with your `imaginaryBankAccount` relation like this :

```
SELECT rec
FROM AppBundle:Recharge rec
JOIN rec.imaginaryBankAccount i
WHERE rec.dateTime > :tresholdDate
AND i.user = :user
ORDER BY rec.dateTime
```